# Why "Docker run" creates new container every time?

Tags: docker, containers

I ran `docker run ubuntu` couple of times. When I list the containers using `docker ps -a`, it list down many containers with different ID. Why does docker creates new container every time instead of the one which is not in use? Doesn't that container occupies some space? Could someone please clarify ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`docker container run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/) is a shorthand for [`docker container create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_create/) and [`docker container start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_start/). So, by definition, it creates a new container every time.

```
$ docker container run --help

Usage:  docker container run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container
```

You can start stopped containers (perhaps created by `docker container run`) with `docker container start …`.

Comment: You can start stopped containers with `docker start <container>`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`docker run --rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm) to "automatically clean up the container and remove the file system when the container exits." Essentially, `docker run --rm` is shorthand for `docker container create`, then `docker container start`, then `docker container rm`.

Answer (score -1):

We need to start same container. We should not create new container every time.

get all container by using below command

c:> docker container ls --all

start container

c:> docker start <container_id>